# Google play store flutter app rejection - Version Code 199

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-play-services

I received a rejection after updating my app to the google play store. I've made several releases but now have received the following email rejection:

```
Issue found: Violation of Device and Network Abuse policy

We reviewed SDKs used by your app and found noncompliant version(s) of SDK(s) which contain code to download or install applications from unknown sources outside of Google Play.

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

Version code 199:
SDK: Dcloud
To bring your app into compliance, follow these steps:

You may consider upgrading to a policy-compliant version of this SDK, if available from your SDK provider or removing the SDK.
Dcloud: Consider upgrading to a policy-compliant version of the SDK if available from your SDK provider, or removing the SDK.
```

The email is not very informative so I don't know how to fix it. It is also the first time for my seeing the term Dcloud. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to upgrade your sdk version to the latest version.